# Manage multiple accounts in different companies with django

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant, django-organizations

I'm learning and working with django less than a year ago. Now I have to develop a site managing multiple users separated by many different companies. I've recently found **django-organizations** package which seems suitable for this application, I have read the complete documentation in readthedocs, but I can't find simple working example apps to start trying, and the activity on communities like stackoverflow on this subject seems to have decayed two years ago.

Please can anybody tell me if django-organizations is an updated package, compatible with last python and django versions, and provide a source of simple “Hello World”-like examples.

Or, by the other hand, please suggest me the best way/library to manage signup, login, permissions, etc,in a multiple users – multiple company Django web application.

Comment: You can check github repository to see if it's well maintain, last commit-date, number of stars, activity in the issues section, number of forks and number of contributors, these details should reply to your first question. Secondly, in the repo itself is an application called example, which is the Hello world you are looking for. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you jabez. Yes, I already have been exploring their github repo, and most of the material is dated two or more years ago. About the example there, I didn't see any views.py or urls.py, so I was not sure this was a complete functional example.
Now exploring multi-tenancy, in particular Guardian package.

Comment: for my purposes https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules has served me well. As on tenancy, there are 3 main approaches you can take: Isolated Approach, Semi Isolated Approach and Shared Approach, each one with its own pros and cons, you should select the one which fits best to your needs. I'd start with a shared approach and as the product grows slowly transition to an isolated approach.